# Unable to see server location while installing apache in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat8

I am trying to install Apache tomcat in eclipse. When I am doing New-> Server, I am getting the following window

[image]

After clicking on next, It is not asking for Tomcat installation directory and I am not able to run it. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Probably you were installed Tomcat and have deleted manually. You have two options:

1. delete or change your `workspace` address in Eclipse and then try to install Tomcat again. It will work.
2. delete the Tomcat configuration files from `workspace` folder as following:

   1. Close your Eclipse
   2. got to `{workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings`
   3. delete these files

      - `org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs`
      - `org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs`
   4. start Eclipse again
   5. install Tomcat again

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlGJD.png)

Comment: I changed workspace and deleted org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs file, but it didn't work org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs, this one I am not able to find.

Comment: I am using Mac OS and this file isn't there. I had to get a new version of eclipse to make it work. Anyway thanks for help :)